# Displaying HTML files from s USB drive on an Android device

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, web, browser

I have developed a stand alone web based application, i.e. no internet required, that resides on a USB drive. It works on a PC in most browsers (Those that support Local/Session Storage for the file:// protocol). In the address bar of the browser enter file://g:/MyApp/default.html      and the application works as expected. However, I can't get this to work on an  Android device, i.e. my phone.

I have the proper cable to connect a standard USB "A" drive to the USB port on the phone. I can see the drive and transfer files but I can not render the html files in the Chrome browser. Don't know what I need to do to get this to work.

Comment: You can use the in built `HTML viewer` for viewing HTML files. When you click the HTML file, select chrome or HTML Viewer from the list.

Comment: I click on the file and it opens in Chrome. I don't get the option of choosing which viewer to use. Furthermore, the page does not render properly, but the javascript appears to be working as it times out and tries to advance to the next page. Chrome then states "Your file was not found". As I said earlier, this works on a Windows PC/tablet.